# after effects slider control code help

Tags: after-effects-expressions

I'm trying to make a slider that basically can act as a crossfader between a bunch of different layers (so as the slider goes up, it fades through several layers). This is what I've written, and I'm getting the error "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected Token )" on the first line and I'm having trouble telling where the problem is.
My code:

```
if(thisComp.layer("Null 1").effect("Slider Control")("Slider") <= 5)
{
    if(thisComp.layer("Null 1").effect("Slider Control")("Slider") <= 2.5)
    {
        out = linear("Null 1").effect("Slider Control")("Slider"), 0, 100, 0, 2.5);
    }
    else
    {
        out = linear("Null 1").effect("Slider Control")("Slider"), 0, 100, 2.5, 5);
        out = 100 - out;
    }
    }
}
else{
    out = 0;
}
out;
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that you've got a stray bracket, so count your brackets and see if the `(`s match the `)`s. Spoiler alert: they don't.

I can see two cases: after each `linear` function call you have a closing bracket after the `"Null 1"` string that isn't matched by an opening bracket. And `"Null 1"` on its own is just treated as a string, not a layer, so that's another problem.

I'm assuming you mean `thisComp.layer("Null 1")` which is a reference to a layer. So

```
out = linear("Null 1").effect("Slider Control")("Slider"), 0, 100, 0, 2.5);
```

should be

```
out = linear(thisComp.layer("Null 1").effect("Slider Control")("Slider"), 0, 100, 0, 2.5);
```

Comment: I got it working, thank you!

Comment: Don't thank me, mash that tick button!